# I am getting this error when trying to run my flutter app on a mac

Tags: flutter

Xcode's output:
↳
1 warning generated.
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/MediaTeam/Documents/hopeapp/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/MediaTeam/Documents/hopeapp/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.

Comment: According to the error xcode is unable to find the build files. Do you have any compilation errors?

Comment: I don't have any errors poping up but this is what I get on the debug console